# How to kill an active session in Weblogic Forms and Reports, when Forms are open by other users?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracleforms

We deploy our changes to Oracle WebLogic Forms and Reports after EOD (after 7/8 pm).
We have over 50 users who open WebLogic URL for Forms and Reports, and some users leave it open.

How to identify those active sessions and kill sessions, in order to make our deployment process smooth?

Answer (score 0):

Access the "User Sessions" page of Fusion Middleware Control.  From there you can see who has running sessions.  You can also kill any or all the sessions if you'd like.  However, keep in mind that when you kill running sessions they may have unsaved changed that will be lost.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/developer-tools/forms/12.2.1.4/working-forms/configuring-and-managing-forms-services.html#GUID-30CE2854-C8E8-4BA3-81A6-B9EFF78D7F23